# Google Drive API latency on Delete Permissions

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive APIs to;

1. remove permissions on a folder (let's call it Folder A)
2. get files and subfolders of Folder A and for each remove permissions

I sometimes get errors at step 2.

Is this because when Step 2 executes, permissions from Step 1 may still be being removed?

Comment: Please make sure to add relevant information to your question, based on the information you have right now we can only assume, please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Subsequent to further testing I can confirm that there is a propagation delay with Google Drive removing permissions on subfolders which have permissions inherited from the parent (when permissions are removed at the parent).

A delay is to be expected but there doesn't appear to be a way to manage this other than introducing a delay before querying subfolders prior to removing any residual (non-inherited) permissions.